# how to prevent ctrl-v in custom ajax toolkit editor?

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, toolkit, keydown

Hi
I have succesfully made a custom ajax toolkit with a few buttoms in the footer toolbar as I wish. Now I also want to avoid crtl-v and right-click paste, but have searched, searched and tried everything with no result ... Maybe someone can lead me on the right track, I hope :)

Here below is my code (used with c# on asp.net web pages) which makes a editor control. The first part works, but the last part with the keydown is not working and maybe completely wrong?

Best regards,
Lars, Denmark

My Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor;


/// <summary>
/// Særlig editor tilrettet behovet hos Boost Company
/// </summary>

namespace AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.BoostToolbarButton
{
    public class Bold : AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.Bold
    {
        public override string ToolTip
        {
            get { return "Fed"; }
        }
    }
    public class Italic : AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.Italic
    {
    public override string ToolTip
        {
            get { return "Kursiv"; }
        }
    }
    public class Cut : AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.Cut
    {
        public override string ToolTip
        {
            get { return "Klip"; }
        }
    }
    public class Copy : AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.Copy
    {
        public override string ToolTip
        {
            get { return "Kopier"; }
        }
    }
    public class PasteText : AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.PasteText
    {
        public override string ToolTip
        {
            get { return "Indsæt"; }
        }
    }
    public class InsertLink : AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.ToolbarButton.InsertLink
    {
        public override string ToolTip
        {
            get { return "Indsæt/ret link"; }
        }
    }
}

namespace BoostKontroller
{

public class BoostEditor : Editor
{
    protected override void FillTopToolbar()
    {
        TopToolbar.Buttons.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.BoostToolbarButton.Bold());
        TopToolbar.Buttons.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.BoostToolbarButton.Italic());
        TopToolbar.Buttons.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.BoostToolbarButton.Cut());
        TopToolbar.Buttons.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.BoostToolbarButton.Copy());
        TopToolbar.Buttons.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.BoostToolbarButton.PasteText());
        TopToolbar.Buttons.Add(new AjaxControlToolkit.HTMLEditor.BoostToolbarButton.InsertLink());
    }

    protected override void FillBottomToolbar()
    {

    }

    void OnKeyDown(KeyEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Control && e.KeyCode == Keys.V)
        {
             Clipboard.SetText(string .Empty); ;
        }

    }

}
}
```

Comment: Why do you want to prevent pasting from the clipboard? I have never seen a text field where that'd make sense.

Comment: Where do you have this OnKeyDown from?

Comment: Is the event handler even firing? Shouldn't it have an `object sender` parameter?

Answer (score 1):

You can do that:

```
$find(sControlId).get_editPanel().get_activePanel()._doc.body.onpaste = 
  function onPasteFunction()
  {
    $find(sControlId).get_editPanel().get_activePanel()._paste(false, false);
    return false;
  }
```

`_paste(false, false);` is to paste with plain text if you want the word paste the function is `_paste(true, true);`

`sControlId` is the client id of the editor.